# How to place kartik typeahead above text input

Tags: css, yii, yii2, typeahead.js

How to place typeahead results above the text input ? The best for me would be adding an option to this widget or maybe some css rule ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment i finally used `jQuery` solution in `render` event of typeahead widget, by modifying css `margin-top` after each render. Here is the code:

```
echo Typeahead::widget([
//(...)
     'pluginEvents' => [
        'typeahead:render' => 'function(event,ui) {

            var ttMenu = $("#search-main .tt-menu").first();
            var ttMenuHeight;

            if($(ttMenu).hasClass("tt-open")) {
                ttMenuHeight = -$(ttMenu).height();
                $(ttMenu).css("margin-top", ttMenuHeight - 70);
            }
        }',
    ],
//(...)
]);
```

`'#search-main .tt-menu'` is my selector for typeahead input, and this "`70`" is height of this input so be sure to replace it with your own.

Hope it helps.